# Is it possible to use a repeat group to iterate over a space-separated list?

Tags: commcare

I know that repeat groups can operate in a few different ways:

1. With a fixed repeat count (the repeat count is an integer loaded in from a hidden variable)
2. With an unspecified repeat group (the repeat group continues until the mobile worker decides to exit the loop)
3. With a Model Iteration ID Query (I've seen this used primarily to iterate over cases retrieved from the casedb)

Is there a 4th option that allows you to iterate over a space-separated list of items, and access each subsequent item as a hidden variable inside the repeat group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A repeat group is capable of iterating over a space separated list with a Model Iteration query, but like any repeat group auto-expansion, this can only occur over a set of values which is **fixed** when the form opens.

That means the list can't be determined by user input in the form, unless you follow the pattern where the repeat contains an entry for every **possible** selection, and uses Display Conditions around an inner group to hide elements which aren't chosen.

With those caveats: You can actually accomplish this quite simply, by providing the path to the space separated list as the Model Iteration query itself. Model iterations actually internally operate over a space separated list that they generate by performing a

`join(' ', instance('something')/your/iteration/query)`

operation on your input. As such, if you provide a query with only one element, the join will just return your space separated list and proceed as usual!

EDIT: Forgot to mention - if you are going to use this method and reference a question *inside the form* (rather tthan an instance as in my example) it needs to:

- Be set it using a **default value**, not a calculation
- Needs to come **before** the model iteration loop.

Comment: For Jessica's second part of the question, how would one then reference the current item in repeat that is being iterated over. For example 'apple banana orange' is being iterated over. Would `current()` on iteration 0 be `apple`?

Comment: It would operate the same as model iteration where the assumption of what is being iterated "over" is located in the model iteration's "id" attribute.

`current()` isn't really relevant to the ID specifically, as the value of current depends on the relative context of the element, but at a high level it would be `repeat_root/item/@id` that contains the value being iterated over.

Answer (score 2):

It might make more sense to just use a regular repeat group without model iteration. You can make the repeat count equal to the number of words in your space-separated list and then load the n-th word into each repeat.  This strategy would work even if your list is calculated within the form.

To calculate the number of words, use the `count-selected()` function.  To get the n-th word, use the `selected-at()` function.

Comment: I prefer this solution, but I'm actually not sure how you would use CommCare functions to extract the nth word from a space-separated string. Can you write a simple function that does this? My solution to this problem was to figure out the Modal Iteration interface.

Comment: The selected-at() function grabs the nth word from a space-separated string.  Syntax: selected-at(my_question, number).  :)

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know about this function! Can you add the specific function name to your original answer?